# Indentation Error after While Loop in Python

Tags: python

I have the following function, I receive an `Indentation Error` whenever I try to run it:

```
def fib(n):    
    # write Fibonacci series up to n
    """Print a Fibonacci series up to n."""
a, b = 0, 1
while a < n:
print a
a, b = b, a+b
 # Now call the function we just defined:
fib(2000)
```

Error message:

```
print a
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

How do I resolve an IndentationError error in python?

Comment: welcome to programming with python where indentation screws you up. basically you need to make sure you use a tab or space and not both.

Comment: why does this question have so many downvotes?

Answer (score 1):

You need to indent your code properly. Just like other languages use brackets, Python uses indentation:

```
def fib(n):    
    # write Fibonacci series up to n
    """Print a Fibonacci series up to n."""
    a, b = 0, 1

    while a < n:
        print a
        a, b = b, a+b
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, you need to add spaces.
Your code must be like this:

```
def fib(n):    
# write Fibonacci series up to n
"""Print a Fibonacci series up to n."""
      a, b = 0, 1

      while a < n:

            print a

            a, b = b, a+b

 # Now call the function we just defined:
fib(2000)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just because syntax. After the while loop come to new line and give Tab and start writing statement like below.

```
>>> while a < 10:    *#this is your condition end with colon ':'*                             
...     print(a)      *#once come to new line press Tab button it will resolve problem*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def fib(n):    
a, b = 0, 1
while a < n:
    print (a, end=' ')
    a, b = b, a+b
    print()
    fib(1000)
```